# Find and recursively delete (with query) consecutive duplicate words not necessarily in the same line and/or same case

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace, words, query-replace-regexp

I would like to scan through a (latex) document and recursively delete -- WITH QUERY -- all consecutive, repeated words that need not be on the same line and/or the same case.  Here is a simple example of the sort of texts I have in mind.

```
This is an example Example of the sort of texts I would
would like to handle.
```

I have found two previous emacs.stackexchange posts on this topic:

[regexp to find two consecutive and identical words not necessarily in the same line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26421/regexp-to-find-two-consecutive-and-identical-words-not-necessarily-in-the-same-l)

[Find and remove consecutive duplicated words while ignoring case](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42444/find-and-remove-consecutive-duplicated-words-while-ignoring-case)

Is there a way to combine these two AND add

- the ability to delete the duplicate word, with query -- ie ask me before deleting it
- recursively run through the whole document (eg like flyspell)

Bonus request: Is it possible to highlight the repeated word (eg like flyspell)?

I'm complete newbie to regexp; thanks for your patience and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query-replace-regexp` with the following parameters:

- `\b\(\w+\)\W+\1` for matching a word (saved as a matching subexpression by means of `\(` and `\)`), followed by non-word characters, then followed by the saved first word. `\b` matches a word delimiter, to avoid matching parts of words.
- `\1` as the replacement (the matched word)

If you want to highlight double words, then use the same matching expression with `highlight-regexp`.

Comment: You have to check for case sensitive or not. Default is insensitive. For more information `C-h f query-replace-regexp RET`